# Delete directory in C

Tags: c, windows

I am wanting to delete a directory in C, Windows. I understand that I must first delete all files within the directory, which is the part that I am confused about. I have found `SHFileOperation` and `IFileOperation` although I don't understand how they are implemented from the documentation.

My current implementation:

```
int dir_exists = 0;
snprintf(dir_name, STR_SIZE, "%s\\%s", LOCAL_DIR, tokens[1]);

// Check if directory exists
DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(dir_name);
if (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
    dir_exists = 1;
}

if (dir_exists == 1) {

    // Remove contents of directory (CURRENTLY UNIX)
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *d;
    char filepath[FNAME_SIZE];
    dir = opendir(dir_name);
    while (d = readdir(dir)) {
        sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", dir_name, d->d_name);
        remove(filepath);
    }

    // Remove directory
    if ((RemoveDirectory(dir_name)) == 0) {
        printf("Error removing dictionary\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am wanting a Windows replacement to the section commented **WITHOUT** use of `#include <dirent.h>` as my VS does not have this header file:

```
// Remove contents of directory (CURRENTLY UNIX)
```

Comment: What *Win* version are you on? Also what *VStudio* version are you using?

Comment: @CristiFati `Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]` and `MSVS 2017`

Comment: So, besides the `SHFileOperation`  (or better  `IFileOperation`), you could continue on the path you started, by writing a recursive function that deletes files and dirs from a specific dir (for that, use `DeleteFile` + `FindFirst` / `FindNext`). But, since this functionality was already implemented, you should probably spend some time on the `IFileOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution credit: [Link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?239271-Windows-SDK-File-System-How-to-delete-a-directory-and-subdirectories)

As the solution says, please be careful when using this function and make sure that you double null terminate `pFrom`.

```
dir_name[STR_SIZE];
int dir_exists = 0;
snprintf(dir_name, STR_SIZE, "folder/dir_to_be_deleted");

// Check if directory exists
DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(dir_name);
if (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
    dir_exists = 1;
}

if (dir_exists == 1) {

    // Remove contents of directory 
    snprintf(dir_name, STR_SIZE, "%s/%s", LOCAL_DIR, tokens[1]);
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, dir_name);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

    int len = _tcslen(szDir);
    TCHAR* pszFrom = malloc((len + 4) * sizeof(TCHAR)); //4 to handle wide char
    StringCchCopyN(pszFrom, len + 2, szDir, len + 2);
    pszFrom[len] = 0;
    pszFrom[len + 1] = 0;

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop;
    fileop.hwnd = NULL;    // no status display
    fileop.wFunc = FO_DELETE;  // delete operation
    fileop.pFrom = pszFrom;  // source file name as double null terminated string
    fileop.pTo = NULL;    // no destination needed
    fileop.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT;  // do not prompt the user
    fileop.fAnyOperationsAborted = FALSE;
    fileop.lpszProgressTitle = NULL;
    fileop.hNameMappings = NULL;

    if (SHFileOperation(&fileop) != 0) {
        printf("Error SHFileOperation\n");
        return 0;
    }
    free(pszFrom);

    // Remove directory
    if ((RemoveDirectory(dir_name)) == 0) {
        printf("Error removing dictionary\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program to list all files and directories in a folder:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry

    // opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type. 
    DIR *dr = opendir(".");

    if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory" );
        return 0;
    }

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", de->d_name);

    closedir(dr);    
    return 0;
}
```

It seems less complicated than your code.
It should be easy to find out by looking at the dirent structure for each entry in the folder whether or not it is a directory and if so abort. Then change the printf to some kind of delete statement for the files.

You may need to call stat to tell file or directory.

Comment: Thank you, but I know how to do this in *nix OS. My question asks specifically for Windows OS

Comment: @Wizard -  just tested it on Windows 10 and it works.

Comment: @melponene - fixed (if you gave the -1 maybe you can undo it.)

Comment: @Marichyasana If you don't spell my name right, I won't get a message notification. :-)

Comment: @Marichyasana my VS doesn't have `#include <dirent.h>` so I will specify in the question

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple windows batch file that will do the job.

```
@echo off
echo (batch file to remove a directory on windows)
cd  /d %tmp%
for /d %%i in (*) do (echo this directory contains a folder "%%i") & (echo so it cannot be deleted) & (goto :END)
for /r %%i in (*) do (echo del %%i)
:END
```

Change the 3rd line to use your directory. Remove 'echo' on line 5.
If you are locked into using 'c' you can use 'system()' to run it.